# How can I convert javascript json data to be x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to send data to my server with a content type of this:

```
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Here's the data that I have from my AngularJS client:

```
 user.loginData = {
        userName: "joe@joe.com",
        password: "smith++"
    };
```

Can someone help by telling me how I can transform the userName and password so I can 
send this data in a urlencoded form to my server:

```
data: 'grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very simple solution:

```
encodeURIComponent(userName)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-urlencoded)   **converts an object to what you want:**

```
var formurlencoded = require('form-urlencoded');
var obj = {
  str : 'val',
  num : 0,
  arr : [3, {prop : false}, 1, null, 6],
  obj : {prop1 : null, prop2 : ['elem']}
};

console.log(formurlencoded(obj));
// str=val&num=0&arr%5B%5D=3&arr%5B%5D%5Bprop%5D=false&arr% 
// 5B%5D=1&arr%5B%5D=null&arr%5B%5D=6&obj%5Bprop1%5D=null&o 
// bj%5Bprop2%5D%5B%5D=elem 

console.log(formurlencoded(obj, {
  ignorenull : true,
  sorted : true
}));
// arr%5B%5D=3&arr%5B%5D%5Bprop%5D=false&arr%5B%5D=1&arr%5B 
// %5D=6&num=0&obj%5Bprop2%5D%5B%5D=elem&str=val
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below line to set the content type

```
query: {method:'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
```

You can check the fiddle link here [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/WkFHH/7/)

Comment: Sorry but your answer does not seem to match the question :-(